# Convert some objects in a list into int

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist, type-conversion

So I am reading a csv file, hitting an API with the inputs in the csv file and then printing the response into another file using Python.

Right now, my csv file consists of 12 request parameters out of which i want 9 to be passed as integer and 3 to be passed as strings while hitting the API.

I am not able to convert them into integers. 
My code uptil now is as below(Have skipped the API part for now):

```
filepath = '/Users/AKG/Work/September19/U-model/Search.csv' 
import requests 
import json
import csv
import os
url = "http://internal-dsp-listing-lg-x.com/v1/predict/RSLD/v1" 
fp = open(filepath, encoding='utf-8') 
for cnt, line in enumerate(fp):
    line = line.split(',')
    d = {"customer_id": line[0],"listing_slot": line[1],"closingIn": line[2],"new_user": line[3],"last_mile_distance": line[4],"stress": line[5],"customer_user_agent": line[6],"listing_restaurant_sla": line[7],"request_id": line[8],"ld": line[9],"city_id": line[10],"restaurant_id": line[11].replace("\n","")} 
    print (line)
```

My output is :

```
['\ufeff87068', '4', '-1', '0', '0.916999995708465', '0.9608271718025208', 'ANDROID', '33', 'aa27f680-2ddb-4d61-b685-e29a15f9c85b', '1', '1', '498\n']
['87068', '4', '-1', '0', '0.916999995708465', '0.9608271718025208', 'ANDROID', '33', 'aa27f680-2ddb-4d61-b685-e29a15f9c85b', '0', '1', '498\n']
```

Q.1 How can I convert some of the elements of this array into integer?

Q.2 How can I remove "\ufeff" in the first element of the first row?

Q.3 How can I remover \n in the last element of the array? I am using the replace function for the last element.

Comment: Q1, `int(str_value_to_convert)`. Q2/Q3. `.replace` or `.strip`. Strip without parameters will remove all whitespace from beginning and end of the string, including `\n`

Comment: Also: **You print `line`, not `d`, so you see things without your replacement. ;)** Your `.replace('\n', '')` is correct.

Comment: `\ufeff` means **BOM** - [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you *could* check whether each character in a substring `isdigit`, or just `try` to convert to `int`, I'd recommend against doing so. What if a segment that *should* be left a string for some reason also contains only digits? Also, note that you also have parts that might need conversion to `float`.
Instead, I'd recommend using a list of types to determine how each part should be converted, then `zip`ing the two and doing the actual conversion.

```
>>> line = '\ufeff87068,4,-1,0,0.916999995708465,0.9608271718025208,ANDROID,33,aa27f680-2ddb-4d61-b685-e29a15f9c85b,1,1,498\n'
>>> items_raw = line.strip().lstrip('\ufeff').split(",")
>>> types = [int, int, int, int, float, float, str, int, str, int, int, int]
>>> items = [t(x) for t, x in zip(types, items_raw)]    
>>> items
[87068, 4, -1, 0,
 0.916999995708465, 0.9608271718025208,
 'ANDROID',
 33,
 'aa27f680-2ddb-4d61-b685-e29a15f9c85b',
 1, 1, 498]
```

You could also use multiplication on lists to make the `types` list a bit shorter and possibly more readable, in particular if there are even more entries in the list:

```
types = [int] * 4 + [float] * 2 + [str, int, str] + [int] * 3
```

Similarly, you can create another lists for the names of the fields, and `zip` them with the items in a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> fields = ["customer_id","listing_slot","closingIn","new_user","last_mile_distance","stress","customer_user_agent","listing_restaurant_sla","request_id","ld","city_id","restaurant_id"]
>>> d = {f: x for f, x in zip(fields, items)}
```

Or combine it with the type conversion in a single dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> d = {f: t(x) for f, t, x in zip(fields, types, items_raw)}
```

Either way, `d` ends up as

```
{'city_id': 1,
 'closingIn': -1,
 'customer_id': 87068,
 'customer_user_agent': 'ANDROID',
 'last_mile_distance': 0.916999995708465,
 'ld': 1,
 'listing_restaurant_sla': 33,
 'listing_slot': 4,
 'new_user': 0,
 'request_id': 'aa27f680-2ddb-4d61-b685-e29a15f9c85b',
 'restaurant_id': 498,
 'stress': 0.9608271718025208}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. 
I also want to add the names of the request parameters, for them to be passed in the API call. 
I am unable to understand where I can add them. 
In my original code, I had added d = {"customer_id": line[0],......

Comment: Currently my output is : 

[87068, 4, -1, 0, 0.916999995708465, 0.9608271718025208, 'ANDROID', 33, 'aa27f680-2ddb-4d61-b685-e29a15f9c85b', '1', 1, 498]
{"errorCode":"Exception","errorBody":{},"status":0}

However, I want the request to be like  {"rdc_name": 87068, "listing_slot" : 4, "closingIn": -1, .......

Answer (score 0):

> My output is :

**You print `line`, not `d`, so you see things without your replacement. ;)** Your `.replace('\n', '')` is correct.

---

Q2/Q3. Yes. You can do `.replace` or `.strip`. Strip without parameters will remove all whitespace from beginning and end of the string, including `\n`

If you replace your simple split with this:

```
line = [elem.strip().replace('\ufeff', '') for elem in line.split(',')]
```

You make sure no element has whitespace at the beginning nor end and that no element has this unicode character.

---

Q1. It's `int(str_value_to_convert)` (so `int(line[0]` and so on).

But to not put so many `int()` in there, you can use this line:

```
line = [int(elem) if elem.isdigit() or (elem[0] == '-' and elem[1:].isdigit()) else elem for elem in line]
```

`.isdigit()` checks whether all characters in the string are digits. Doesn't work for negative integers (because `-` is not a digit), so I made `or` with checking whether first character is a minus and whether the rest of the string is digit-only.

---

Another useful change is how you create your dictionary. Because you use elements from `line` in order, we can just zip it with the list of labels and use explicit `dict` constructor:

```
for cnt, line in enumerate(fp):
    line = [elem.strip().replace('\ufeff', '') for elem in line.split(',')]
    line = [int(elem) if elem.isdigit() or (elem[0] == '-' and elem[1:].isdigit()) else elem for elem in line]
    d = dict(zip(["customer_id","listing_slot","closingIn","new_user","last_mile_distance","stress","customer_user_agent","listing_restaurant_sla","request_id","ld","city_id","restaurant_id"], line))
```